# Crud operation in SharePoint using AngularJS

Tags: sharepoint-online, angularjs

I have tried to implement crud operation in SharePoint using AngularJS. I have followed this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1002526/SharePoint-and-Angularjs).

But in this case, it is taking the appwebURL instead of hostwebURL. So it is not able to retrieve or insert data to SharePoint list.

So I wanted to know, how do we handle appwebURl and HostwebURL when we use AngularJS for SharePoint Hosted Apps.

[image]

Comment: URL in the screenshot is the host web URL. It is not the App web URL. If you want to be over sure then paste the URL in your browser. It will redirect you to the host site.

Answer (score 1):

It is not taking app web url. May be you have missed the last part of my article.

For SharePoint Hosted App,  `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl` will give you the host web url.

Check the following part again.

> In the `baseSvc.js`, we have to use `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl`
> instead of `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl` for `baseUrl`.

**PS:** In my sample code there is a working solution. My app is using host web's list. So you should not face any issue if you are following my sample code properly.

## To your Last update

You have posted the screenshot with the value of `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl`. Yes it is pointing to the host web url. Just try to operate CRUD.

App web I mean the value of `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl` should be different. According to your screenshot, it should be

```
https://site-guid.sharepoint.com/sites/test1/{appName}
```

Comment: when I deploy it, App page is opened and then I have checked in the browser `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl` gives me the same app page url.

Comment: still you are missing something. see my updated answer.